# Unity window title and elements text is not show (KSP)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, modulo

I'm a newbie in KSP mod creation, trying to make a GUI for my mod. I caught an issue with displaying text on GUI elements. For example I created a window with button and window had no title, button had no text on it. Button is work and I see debug message after click.

I tried to use `GUI` instead of `GUILayout` but had the same issue. I tried to use `HighLogic.Skin.window` for window in `GUILayout.Window(0, this.windowRect, this.DrawWindow, "Title", HighLogic.Skin.window)` and I saw the title of a window, but if I use `HighLogic.Skin.button` in `GUILayout.Button("Press me", HighLogic.Skin.button)` I have this issue again. So, I don't know how to fix it.

Code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

namespace KCSS
{
    [KSPAddon(KSPAddon.Startup.MainMenu, false)]
    public class KCSS : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Rect windowRect;

        private void DrawWindow(int id)
        {
            if(GUILayout.Button("Press me"))
            {
                Debug.Log("[KCSS mod] <color=#f1a12e>Action:</color> Button pressed");
            }

            GUI.DragWindow();
        }

        public void Awake()
        {
            Debug.Log("[KCSS mod] <color=#66cccc>Load:</color> KCSS main class");

            this.windowRect = new Rect(50, 50, 150, 100);
        }

        public void OnGUI()
        {
            this.windowRect = GUILayout.Window(0, this.windowRect, this.DrawWindow, "Title");
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of an issue:
[No text on title and button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIfAa.png)

Screenshot if I use `HighLogic.Skin`: [No button text only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WFax.png)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by installing `ttf-ms-fonts`. If you are on Linux you have to do that if making KSP mods.